# Including a gem's assets in my asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm using the [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin in my rails app.

Initially, I placed the jQuery plugin directly in my app's assets folder, and required individual files like so:

```
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.js
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload-process.js
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload-validate.js
```

This worked great. However, I now need to use the gem-ified version of the jQuery plugin ([jquery-fileupload-rails](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails)) in order to satisfy the requirements for another gem I'm using. After installing the gem, per the documentation I include it with the following line:

```
//= require jquery-fileupload
```

The problem is, the gem manifest doesn't include two of the files I need, and when I try to add them individually, I get a `Sprockets::FileNotFound` error:

```
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload-process.js
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload-validate.js
```

The files are in the gem's directory, I just can't seem to access them. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Put your `jquery-fileupload-rails` gem inside `:assets` group in the gemfile

Comment: I tried what you suggested, it doesn't do anything. Moreover I don't understand the logic- How does limiting the gem to a particular group enable any of the asset paths?

Comment: Asset group includes the gem into assets pipeline. Sometimes it makes some dependencies, for example with twitter-bootstrap.
Have you tried requiring them them like `//= jquery.fileupload-validate` (without any folder or file extension)?